Intuition for Why Resampling Should Create New Information
If one plots a bootstrap distribution of "resample means" obtained by resampling a single, real sample from a population distribution, the mean of that plot gives no more information than the sample does about the mean of the population distribution.  However, it is purported to give more information than the sample does about the variance and skewness (and I assume all higher order moments) of the population distribution.
Apparently very related (perhaps even a generalization of the above) is the fact that bagging in machine learning succeeds at reducing the variance of an algorithm despite that the only "new" data fed to the algorithm was entirely derived from resampling the single, real sample.
Similarly, taking for granted the effectiveness of using a single validation set to predict testing error/generalizability, cross-validation still seems mysterious; if one partitions real data into two sets, computes some statistic, then repeats using each possible partition of the same real data (perhaps disallowing two such validation sets to contain the same data point), it seems  like the resulting statistics should depend on each other in a sense that to try to extract new information out of each statistic is to look for a free lunch.
Is there some mathematical intuition for why it is reasonable to expect new information to be created out of a fixed sample ex nihilo just by shuffling it around?  Is it possible, either in principle or in practice, to visualize a sample in the right way or apply some deterministic mathematical formula to it to derive this ostensibly new information without resampling, or does the process of resampling create something genuinely not already encoded in the sample?

I wouldn't say that new information is created, rather existing information is discovered, just like any other manipulation of data

No new information is created.  Resampling doesn't create new information or give more information than could be obtained from the sample.  Indeed, the resampling procedure works with the sample, so anything you get from it is information that is obtained from the sample.  I suspect you have misunderstood what was being claimed, or else the claim was wrong.

Is it possible then to find some deterministic formula to apply to the sample to attain that hidden information?

@user10478, Yes.  Resampling is an approximation to a deterministic procedure, where you compute the exact expectation over resamples (e.g., you enumerate all possible resamples, compute the value of the estimator for each resample, and average them).
